# creating index matrix based on line number of a cell arrey matlab

Tags: matlab

We are given a cell array `Ref_M` of size m x n, and a matrix `IMG` of size L x C.
The purpose is split the `IMG` matrix to 2x2 blockes, then create a new matrix `IMG_New` contain numbers that refers to which line in the `Ref_M` the block is belongs to.

Given:

```
Ref_M = [1 1; 1 1]    [2 2; 2 2]    [ 9 9; 9 9]
        [3 3; 3 3]    [5 5; 5 5]    [] 
        [6 6; 6 6]    [4 4; 4 4]    []
        [7 7; 7 7]    []            []

IMG =[1 1 2 2 2 2 5 5;
      1 1 2 2 2 2 5 5;
      4 4 5 5 6 6 9 9;
      4 4 5 5 6 6 9 9;
      3 3 9 9 1 1 7 7;
      3 3 9 9 1 1 7 7]
```

the first block from the `IMG` is:

```
1 1
1 1
```

now we need to define in which row in the `Ref_M` that block is belongs, and as we can see it is belongs to the first row, therefore the first element of the `IMG_New` should be 1

```
IMG_New = [1]
```

the second block from the `IMG` is:

```
2 2
2 2
```

now we need to define in which row in the `Ref_M` that block is belongs, and as we can see it is belongs also to the first row, therefore the second element of the `IMG_New` should be 1 also

```
IMG_New = [1 1]
```

the thing about the third block

```
2 2
2 2
```

whan it's come the the block number four:

```
5 5
5 5
```

we need to define in which row in the `Ref_M` that block is belongs, and as we can see it is belongs also to the second row, therefore the 4th element of the `IMG_New` should be 2

```
IMG_New = [1 1 1 2]
```

and so on

The totlal result should be:

```
IMG_New = [1 1 1 2;
           3 2 3 1;
           2 1 1 4]
```

Comment: At least for me this is really difficult to follow, could you please add some intermediate steps to explain how you get to `IMG_New`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`blockproc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) with a custom function:

```
ind = blockproc(IMG.', [2 2], @(x) find(cellfun(@(y) isequal(x.data.', y), Ref_M), 1)).';
IMG_new = mod(ind-1, size(Ref_M,1))+1;
```

Notes:

- `[2 2]` in the first line is the desired blocksize.
- This finds the *first* match in `Ref_M` (in case there are several matches).
- The anonymous function `@(x) ...` determines that first match for each block of `IMG`. It uses `cellfun` to do the actual job.
- `ind` contains the linear index within `Ref_M`. The second line computes the row from the linear index.

Comment: thanks!! 
but its not working whan its come to 3x3 blocksize ?

Comment: There were some transposes missing. Please see now. Do you want the output to refer to the _row_ or the _column_ of `Ref_M`? If it's the column, use `Ref_M.'` instead of `Ref_M` in the first line